# Facebook sharedialog issue

Tags: android

I am trying to share an image in facebook from my android app.I am using facebook share dialog for this.But I am always getting an exception that unable to parse textvie.I am not using any textviews in my activity.So please help me.

Following is the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
  xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools";
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  tools:context="com.ss.activities.ShareFB">
</RelativeLayout>
```

and following is error log:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Binary XML
>   file line #41: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) at
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:164) at
>   android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:417)

and following is my code

```
public class ShareFB extends AppCompatActivity {
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ShareDialog shareDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_share_fb);
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
            ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder().setContentUrl(Uri.parse("https://developers.facebook.com")).build();
                shareDialog.show(ShareFB.this, content);
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Still not getting.

Comment: Could you post the logcat showing the exception, and the activity & layout where your TextViews are declared?

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: Binary XML file line #41: Error inflating class android.widget.TextView
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
 at android.app.ProgressDialog.onCreate(ProgressDialog.java:164)
 at android.app.Dialog.dispatchOnCreate(Dialog.java:417)

Comment: I am not using any textviews in my activity

Comment: Can you post your layout xml file for the activity? Looks like that's where the problem is, on line 41.

Comment: Edit your original post to include the layout. Comments only have a limited number of characters.

Comment: My layout is only this much.

Comment: What layout are you passing into your ProgressDialog?

Comment: I dont have any progress dialog

Comment: @SibinDavis it would be more precise if you can add the code of java file as well, the issue seems to be there.

Comment: The logcat you posted above implies that the app has crashed while trying to read a malformed xml layout file. Can you post the activity that's calling the facebook share dialog?